# I want to know how to make a floating button in android studio that remains on the screen even after closing activity

Tags: android-studio

I want to know how to make a floating button or anything extra. In android studio that remains on the screen even after closing activity.

Comment: Please fix your shift key before asking a question.

Comment: Writing all UPPERCASE is considered shouting and rude around here.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the activity is closed (I assume you mean the moment when `onDestroy()` method is called) every thread used by your app is closed until `onCreate()` method is called again.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to make a floating widget like messenger. please follow the bellow link.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-floating-widget-like-facebook-chat-head/

Comment: Although your answer could be 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...